# Printing only last part of line (bash)

Tags: file, printing, sed, awk

My file :

```
field1;field2;field3;stillfield3;andstillfield3
```

expect output, since it has the same separator ";".

```
field3;stillfield3;andstillfield3
```

I already tried awk and sed, but no success!

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: What is the file content and what you are actually expecting to be printed? Give examples for this question

Comment: Try to improve the explanation, as it is not clear what you want. Is it just the string from the 2nd semicolon?

Answer (score 1):

If your requirement is to extract fields 3 and on from a semicolon-delimited text file,

```
cut -d ';' -f3- file >newfile
```